# hosted OCS and my local Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, local, integration

I plan to use hosted BPOS for collaboration but i want my OCS and SharePoint Online integrated with my local Active Directory.

Is this possible and if so, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the microsoft BPOS site in their FAQ it says:

> Q: Is Active Directory required?
>   A: Active Directory is not required for the Standard service, but you can synchronize your existing Active Directory information to the service by using our tool. Active Directory is required for the Dedicated service.

Here is a link to their support page for the service

[MS online services help/support](http://www.microsoft.com/online/help/en-us/helphowto/Migration-Synchronization.htm)